# Replica of expandable list view in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, listview

I want to load several questions and once the question is tapped it shows the drop down for its respective options. How can I implement it in iOS. Please suggest

Comment: you use in the table view drop down list

Comment: How to use drop down list in table view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

[GCRetractableSectionController](https://github.com/gcamp/GCRetractableSectionController)

[Expandingcollapsing-tableView-sections](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/)

Hope this helps.